# Rx how to create a sequence from a pub/sub pattern

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, publish-subscribe, producer-consumer

I'm trying to evaluate using Rx to create a sequence from a pub/sub pattern (i.e. classic observer pattern where next element is published by the producer(s)). This is basically the same as .net events, except we need to generalize it such that having an event is not a requirement, so I'm not able to take advantage of Observable.FromEvent.  I've played around with Observable.Create and Observable.Generate and find myself end up having to write code to take care of the pub/sub (i.e. I have to write producer/consumer code to stash the published item, then consume it by calling IObserver.OnNext() with it), so it seems like I'm not really taking advantage of Rx...

Am I looking down the correct path or is this a good fit for Rx?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your publisher just exposes some `IObservables` as properties.  And your consumers just `Subscribe` to them (or do any Rx-fu they want before subscribing).

Sometimes this is as simple as using `Subjects` in your publisher.  And sometimes it is more complex because your publisher is actually observing some other observable process.

Here is a dumb example:

```
public class Publisher
{
    private readonly Subject<Foo> _topic1;

    /// <summary>Observe Foo values on this topic</summary>
    public IObservable<Foo> FooTopic
    {
       get { return _topic1.AsObservable(); }
    }

    private readonly IObservable<long> _topic2;

    /// <summary>Observe the current time whenever our clock ticks</summary>
    public IObservable<DateTime> ClockTickTopic
    {
        get { return _topic2.Select(t => DateTime.Now); }
    }

    public Publisher()
    {
         _topic1 = new Subject<Foo>();
         // tick once each second
         _topic2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }

    /// <summary>Let everyone know about the new Foo</summary>
    public NewFoo(Foo foo) { _topic1.OnNext(foo); }
}


// interested code...
Publisher p = ...;
p.FooTopic.Subscribe(foo => ...);

p.ClickTickTopic.Subscribe(currentTime => ...);

// count how many foos occur during each clock tick
p.FooTopic.Buffer(p.ClockTickTopic)
    .Subscribe(foos => Console.WriteLine("{0} foos during this interval", foos.Count));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using RX is definitely a good fit for pub/sub. Here is a demo that illustrates the simplest possible pub/sub pattern using `IObservable` and RX.

Add Reactive Extensions (RX) to your project using NuGet, search for `rx-main` and install `Reactive Extensions - Main Library`.

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

namespace RX_2
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Subject<int> stream = new Subject<int>();

            stream.Subscribe(
                o =>
                {
                    Console.Write(o);
                });

            stream.Subscribe(
                o =>
                {
                    Console.Write(o);
                });

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                stream.OnNext(i);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When executed, the code outputs this:

```
0011223344
```

Comment: In order to compile this code, you will have to add RX to your solution using NuGet.