# How do I access MainPage class non-static members from the App class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I have added an application bar to my blank Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app as per MSDN documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394038(v=vs.105).aspx. I have added event handlers encapsulated within the App class to each of the buttons in the application bar. I need a way of accessing the current instance of MainPage class from the App class so I may call non-static methods in the MainPage class to update the UI. I have Binged for hours but I have not come across a solution.  I came across this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13314364/3998051 but the question it was answering is sort of the reverse of my question. Sadly, the solution isn't. Would you please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this problem using Reactive Extensions (RX).

You can add Reactive Extensions (RX) to your project using NuGet, search for `rx-main` and install `Reactive Extensions - Main Library`.

Both of your pages would access a common class which would have a `Subject<T>`. One page would publish events to this `Subject<T>` using `OnNext`, and the other page would subscribe to these events using `Subscribe`.

For a complete worked example, see [Rx how to create a sequence from a pub/sub pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974287/rx-how-to-create-a-sequence-from-a-pub-sub-pattern/).

Comment: Is this a design pattern commonly used in object oriented programming in these kinds of scenario?

Comment: @MoonOwlPrince This has worked well for me, but if there is a better design pattern, I would be very interested to know!

Comment: Thanks for marking this as the accepted answer. I have updated the answer with a link to a worked example.